# How to install c libraries in aws lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, zappa

I'm deploying a deep learning model that uses `mxnet` using `flask` and `zappa`. Everything works fine on the local system. But when I deploy using `zappa deploy myapp` it gives the following error:

```
OSError: libgfortran.so.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was wondering if there's any way to zip these *.so files in the package and then deploy it using `zappa` ?

Comment: might help-https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html